# Akka FileIO.fromPath - How to deal with IOResult and get the data instead?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I looked at a lot of examples and posts about this. I got it working in one way but I haven't quite gotten the idea yet, I'm still getting tripped up by `Future[IOResult]` when I'm trying to read a file into a stream of record objects, one per line, call it `Future[List[LineRecordCaseClass]]` is what I want instead.

```
val source = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/tmp/junk_data.csv"))
val flow = makeFlow() // Framing.delimiter->split(",")->map to LineRecordCaseClass
val sink = Sink.collection[LineRecordCaseClass, List[LineRecordCaseClass]]

val graph = source.via(flow).to(sink)

val typeMismatchError: Future[List[LineRecordCaseClass]] = graph.run()
```

Why does `graph.run()` return a `Future[IOResult]` instead? Perhaps I'm missing a `Keep.left` somewhere, or something?  If so what and where at?

Some concept I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the type of yours `val`s

```
val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = 
val flow: Flow[ByteString, LineRecordCaseClass, NotUsed] = 
val sink: Sink[LineRecordCaseClass, Future[List[LineRecordCaseClass]]] =
```

[From the akka-stream doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#combining-materialized-values) , in the code snippet

> By default, the materialized value of the leftmost stage is preserved

The materialized value at your leftmost stage (the source) is `Future[IOResult]`.

In `source.via(flow).to(sink)`, if you look at the implementation of `.to`, it calls `.toMat` with a default `Keep.left`

The type for `Keep.both` is

```
val check: RunnableGraph[(Future[IOResult], Future[List[LineRecordCaseClass]])] = source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.both)
```

So if you want `Future[List[LineRecordCaseClass]]`, you can do

```
source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
```

I recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-CK76cPB9s) which explains the materialized value